# Does caching jQuery objects in an array improve speed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

Today I was making an effect for share-icons using jQuery. The effect is a bit complicated so I tried to think of a way to optimize preformance. I ended up caching the `$(this)` object into array.

### Effect Demo

I uploaded a working example of the effect using the array-cached objects (Hover on the icons to see the effect):
http://mahersalam.co.cc/addthis/

### HTML:

```
<div id="share-widget" class="addthis_toolbox">
    <a class="addthis_button_favorites" title="أضف للمفضلة"><div>أضف للمفضلة</div></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook" title="شارك في فيسبوك"><div>شارك في فيسبوك</div></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_twitter" title="شارك في تويتر"><div>شارك في تويتر</div></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_email" title="أرسل الصفحة بالإيميل"><div>أرسل الصفحة بالإيميل</div></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_compact" title="أضغط هنا لمشاهدة المزيد من خدمات المشاركة"><div>المزيد من الخدمات</div></a>
</div>
```

### Javascript:

```
// Return jQuery-obj of the share links
var shareLinks = $('#share-widget').find('a').css('opacity', 0.8);

//////////////////////////////////////////
// Only jQuery way
//////////////////////////////////////////

shareLinks.hover( 
    function () {
        $(this).clearQueue()
            .siblings()
                .stop(true,false).fadeTo('fast', 0.3)
            .end()
                .stop(true, true).fadeTo('normal', 1);
    },
    function () {
        shareLinks.delay(100).fadeTo('normal', 0.8);
})


//////////////////////////////////////////
// jQuery + Array cache way
////////////////////////////////////////// 

// Cache the array
var linksArr = [];

$.each( shareLinks, function (i) {

    linksArr.push( $(this) );

    linksArr[i].hover( function () {
        linksArr[i].clearQueue()
                    .siblings()
                        .stop(true,false).fadeTo('fast', 0.3)
                    .end()
                        .stop(true, true).fadeTo('normal', 1);
     },
    function () {
        shareLinks.delay(100).fadeTo('normal', 0.8);
    })
});
```

I just want to know if the array cached objects will make the performance faster or is it just not necessary. Also if anyone have a better idea to make this effect, I'm all ears ^^.

Comment: Learn how to format code and text properly with the http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case it is not necessary. It is even more difficult to understand imo and maybe even slower. In your code:

```
shareLinks.hover( 
    function () {
        $(this).clearQueue()
            .siblings()
                .stop(true,false).fadeTo('fast', 0.3)
            .end()
                .stop(true, true).fadeTo('normal', 1);
    },
    function () {
        shareLinks.delay(100).fadeTo('normal', 0.8);
});
```

you are accessing `$(this)` only once anyway, why do you want to cache it? Afaik, `$(this)` is cheap anyway as it does not cause a search in the DOM.

---

It is only of advantage if you are *evaluating* the same selector several times (e.g. in a loop):

```
for(...) { 
   $('#share-widget div ul li > a').something(i);
}
```

is better written as

```
var $elements = $('#share-widget div ul li > a');
for(...) { 
   $elements.something(i);
}
```

---

**Update:**

Regarding what happens if you call `$(this)`, this is the corresponding part from the code:

```
// Handle $(DOMElement)
if ( selector.nodeType ) {
    this.context = this[0] = selector;
    this.length = 1;
     return this;
}
```

and this is [almost the at the top of the function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L80). So it is really not doing much.

Comment: `shareLinks` is a collection of jQ-objs. So `$(this)` will change for every object. I don't understand why I should make a new jQ-obj when it's already inside `shareLinks`. That's why I added them to an array.

Comment: @Maher4Ever: But this is not a speed issue, because creating a jQuery object from `$(this)` is cheap. This would be more of a memory concern. And besides that, `this` is passed directly in the functions scope, whereas `linksArr` has to be looked up on runtime (ok thi argument is a bit weak because `$` has to be looked up too) and you have an additional array access. Most of the time you don't need to cache `$(this)` because creating it is cheap.

Comment: I thought that `$(this)` was expensive! It's really a good info to know, thank you.

Comment: @Maher4Ever: I mean you should avoid *unnecessary* calls to `$()` but in your case calling `$(this)` is absolutely normal.

Answer (score 1):

The only `caching` I see going on is when you use this line

```
var shareLinks = $('#share-widget').find('a').css('opacity', 0.8);
```

which could perhaps be made faster by combining the (but I doubt it, and it's a single selector, so not that much to worry about here)

```
var shareLinks = $('#share-widget a').css('opacity', 0.8);
```

Everything else I see isn't really caching. Ergo I'm gonna put in my $0.05 and tell you to make it readable first and foremost, because **readable code is maintainable code**. Everything else is fluff for your ego.

Answer (score 1):

One way to improve performance, especially if you have a lot of links, is to use JQuery's [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function:

```
$('#share-widget').delegate('a', 'mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).clearQueue()
        .siblings()
            .stop(true,false)
            .fadeTo('fast', 0.3)
        .end()
            .stop(true, true)
            .fadeTo('normal', 1);
});
$('#share-widget').delegate('a', 'mouseleave', function() {
    shareLinks.delay(100)
        .fadeTo('normal', 0.8);
});
```